# C# Parameters doesn't work in query string

Tags: c#, sql

I ran into some problems doing the update statement in c#. Well, if I write some specific values in the query string like

```
string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName='My Firstname', User_LastName='My Lastname' WHERE User_Username='username'";
```

But when I use the `parameter.Add` to write in the query string, it doesn't work. So what I'm having some troubles with, is how to get parameters to work in my query string.

Here's my script so far

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Break; Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users", connection);
command.Connection.Open();

string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName = @FirstName, User_LastName= @LastName WHERE User_Username = @Username";
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(querystr, connection);

string User_Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
string User_FirstName = FirstNameEdit.Text;
string User_LastName = LastNameEdit.Text;

query.Parameters.Add("@Username", User_Username);
query.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", User_FirstName);
query.Parameters.Add("@LastName", User_LastName);

query.ExecuteNonQuery();

Session.Add("FirstName", User_FirstName);
Session.Add("LastName", User_LastName);

StatusMessage.Text = "Updated!";

command.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: You get any error or exception message? Give us more details about your problem.

Comment: Define " it dosen't work " please ? What exactly happens?

Comment: Please check the exact values of `User_Username`, `User_FirstName` and `User_LastName`, including any leading/trailing whitespace, and including the *case*; depending on the database configuration, `'Kvist'` does not necessarily match `'kvist'`, `'KVIST'` or `'KvIsT'`. Sometimes it does, though - again - depending on the configuration. In particular, if any of those are `null`, things can get very interesting (but: `.Text` doesn't usually return `null`, so that is unlikely to be the issue)

Comment: No error, no nothing, it just dosen't update.

Comment: Why are you opening the first connection and executing the `Select * from Users`? You don't need to and I wonder if it's part of the problem?

Comment: Define "It dosen't work".... well it dosen't and I dont know why, I blame the sqlParameters. But I dont know, that's why I asked you guys.

Comment: Stephen Byrne, as I said, it worked with specific values, but it dosen't work with sqlparameters

Comment: Have you tried to run the query in Management Studio with your desired values you want to add by parameters? Does this work or is this failing also? Check what @MarcGravell said

Comment: And, not regarding to your problem but a common hint. Use "using" statement with SqlConenction as it is implementing IDisposable.

Comment: @Dom84 and `command`, and `query` ;p

Comment: Dom84, Yes, it worked perfectly. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: All I can think of is that `User_Username` does not exist in the table to begin with. Show data please (data in table and value of strings in code).

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 [User_ID]
      ,[User_Username]
      ,[User_Password]
      ,[User_FirstName]
      ,[User_LastName]
  FROM [Break].[dbo].[Users]

Comment: I don't have a Users Table/View. What kind of object is Users? Is it a joined view maybe? I don't know how to handle updates on joined views with sqlserver, under Oracle you have to implement an instead of trigger for something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) instead:

```
query.Parameters.AddwithValue("@Username", User_Username);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `Add` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx ; `Add` works *just fine*. There are *preferred* ways of doing it (hence the `[Obsolete]` - but it fundamentally *works*. Specifically, this overload was removed to avoid an ambiguity, nothing more: "The overload of Add that takes a string and an object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the SqlParameterCollection.Add overload that takes a String and a SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer..."

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to define the parameters in the same order like you defined them in your string.
In former days I encountered problems with that, but i have to say i had used ADO Connection at this time.
But it could be a try.
Maybe the parameters don't get referenced by their names internally.

(But i hope this isn't the problem. Hopefully this has been fixed)

Like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Break; Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users", connection);
command.Connection.Open();

string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName = @FirstName, User_LastName= @LastName WHERE User_Username = @Username";
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(querystr, connection);

string User_Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
string User_FirstName = FirstNameEdit.Text;
string User_LastName = LastNameEdit.Text;

// changed the order of adding values here
query.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", User_FirstName);
query.Parameters.Add("@LastName", User_LastName);
query.Parameters.Add("@Username", User_Username);

query.ExecuteNonQuery();

Session.Add("FirstName", User_FirstName);
Session.Add("LastName", User_LastName);

StatusMessage.Text = "Updated!";

command.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: Positional parameters applies to some ADO.NET providers, and possible some versions of SQL CE, but not to SQL Server via `SqlConnection`

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(querystr, connection);
query.CommandType = CommandType.Text //try to add this line.
```

and also try to open a new sqlconnection for the second sqlcommand.

Comment: `Text` is the default

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate the update query and add new instances of SqlParameters. Also check if `User_Username` variable gets a value that exists in the database.

```
string User_Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
string User_FirstName = FirstNameEdit.Text;
string User_LastName = LastNameEdit.Text;

string cnnStr = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Break; Integrated Security=True";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnnStr))
{
   //Commented as not using
   //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users", connection);
   //command.Connection.Open();

   string querystr = "UPDATE Users SET User_FirstName = @FirstName, User_LastName= @LastName " +
                     "WHERE  User_Username = @Username";
   SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(querystr, connection);

   //Add a new SqlParameter()...
   query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = User_Username;
   query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = User_FirstName;
   query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = User_LastName;

   connection.Open();
   query.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

//Rest of the code
Session.Add("FirstName", User_FirstName);
Session.Add("LastName", User_LastName);
StatusMessage.Text = "Updated!";
```